# How to replace list items in a custom appsettings.json file?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, appsettings

I have custom appsettings.json files for each environment, so appsettings.Dev.json, appsettings.Test.json, appsettings.Prod.json. In the main appsettings.json, I have the following code:

```
  "EmailSettings": {
    "Recipients": [
      "person@test.com"
    ]
  }
```

Then in the custom json file, I want to override this list, like this:

```
  "EmailSettings": {
    "Recipients": [
      "anotherperson@test.com"
    ]
  }
```

But instead, this gets appended like this:

```
  "EmailSettings": {
    "Recipients": [
      "person@test.com",
      "anotherperson@test.com"
    ]
  }
```

With all other types of settings, they get replaced, but for some reason, it seems that lists in custom settings files get appended instead. With .net, you used to have more granularity with the xslt to be able to determine whether you wanted to replace or append overridden settings. Any suggestions here?

### SOLUTION (for me)

I did this, and it gets replaced in the custom json settings. Main appsettings.json:

```
  "EmailSettings": {
    "Recipients:0": "person@test.com"
  }
```

Then in the custom settings file:

```
  "EmailSettings": {
    "Recipients:0": "anotherperson@test.com"
  }
```

Thanks for the responses!

Comment: You can specify emails with comma separated: `"Recipients":"email1,email2"` instead of array.

Comment: Also a good alternative, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `appsettings.Test.json` use the following

`"EmailSettings:Recipients:0" : "anotherperson@test.com"`

The Configuration API is capable of maintaining hierarchical configuration data by flattening the hierarchical data with the use of a delimiter in the configuration keys.

You will need to define the Email Settings class like

```
   public class EmailSettings
    {
        public List<string> Recipients { get; set; }
    }
```

and wireup the DI to add the options in the `Configure` Method in `Startup` class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // add Options
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }
```

Comment: I get this:    "EmailSettings": {
    "Recipients": [
      "person@test.com"
    ]
  },
  "EmailSettings:Recipients:0": "anotherperson@test.com"

Comment: @gabs, I didn't understand what you mentioned in comments, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Ok, it doesn't seem to replace it in the custom json file, it just appends it to the end. I just saw you added more details above, thanks i'll try that out :)

Comment: Ok, I realised what I had to do, thanks to your help :) It seems that I needed to declare the settings in the same way in the main appsettings.json as well as in the custom settings, so it would get replaced! I'll add it in the main body.

Comment: Glad, I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I utilized different `appsettings` files for environments (including `Development`)

So first make sure you have added the environment json file in your configuration:

```
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
```

Then in my original `appsettings.json` it would be something like:

```
"EmailSettings": {
    "Recipients": []
}
```

and then for local development (`Development` environment): `appsettings.Development.json`

```
"EmailSettings": {
    "Recipients": [
        "person@test.com"
    ]
}
```

and then for the other environment (lets call it `Staging`): `appsettings.Staging.json`

```
"EmailSettings": {
    "Recipients": [
        "anotherperson@test.com"
    ]
}
```

Then, just make sure in your additional environments you have set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in environment variables.